# PyTorch's grid_sample conversion to CoreML (via coremltools)

Tags: python, swift, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

`torch.nn.functional.grid_sample` (source [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#grid_sample), click on docs for documentation) is currently unsupported operation by CoreML (and their conversion utilities library: [coremltools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools)).

What I'm looking for is a way to export layer shown below from PyTorch's `torchscript` (docs [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html)) to CoreML (either using custom `op` created via Swift or via efficient PyTorch rewrite of `grid_sample`).

**For details and tips to get you started see Tips section**

### Minimal verifiable example

```
import coremltools as ct
import torch


class GridSample(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, inputs, grid):
        # Rest could be the default behaviour, e.g. bilinear
        return torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(inputs, grid, align_corners=True)


# Image could also have more in_channels, different dimension etc.,
# for example (2, 32, 64, 64)
image = torch.randn(2, 3, 32, 32)  # (batch, in_channels, width, height)
grid = torch.randint(low=-1, high=2, size=(2, 64, 64, 2)).float()

layer = GridSample()
# You could use `torch.jit.script` if preferable
scripted = torch.jit.trace(layer, (image, grid))

# Sanity check
print(scripted(image, grid).shape)


# Error during conversion
coreml_layer = ct.converters.convert(
    scripted,
    source="pytorch",
    inputs=[
        ct.TensorType(name="image", shape=image.shape),
        ct.TensorType(name="grid", shape=grid.shape),
    ],
)
```

which raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/REDACTED/Downloads/sample.py", line 23, in <module>
    coreml_layer = ct.converters.convert(
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/_converters_entry.py", line 175, in convert
    mlmodel = mil_convert(
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 128, in mil_convert
    proto = mil_convert_to_proto(, convert_from, convert_to,
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 171, in mil_convert_to_proto
    prog = frontend_converter(, **kwargs)
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 85, in __call__
    return load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/load.py", line 81, in load
    raise e
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/load.py", line 73, in load
    prog = converter.convert()
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 227, in convert
    convert_nodes(self.context, self.graph)
  File "/home/REDACTED/.conda/envs/REDACTED/lib/python3.9/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/ops.py", line 54, in convert_nodes
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op 'grid_sampler' not implemented.
```

### Dependencies

Python (`conda`):

- `coremltools==4.1`
- `torch==1.8.0`

You could also use `nightly`/`master` builds (at least for the day of writing: `2021-03-20`)

### Tips

Those were split into two possible solutions I currently see:

#### PyTorch only

**Rewrite `torch.nn.functional.grid_sample` from scratch**.

- This would require sticking only to PyTorch operations on tensors as loops (e.g. triple nested) would hang the converter and be too inefficient
- **You cannot use `__getitem__` on `list` or related types** - seems to work with `torch.Tensor` but had problems with that so you should have it in mind if you get `RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op '__getitem__' not implemented`

**Pros:**

- No need for two languages & sticking to single technology

**Cons:**

- Limited with loops and would require sticking to vectorized operations (most/all of the time)

#### Swift & CoreML

**Register custom layer which is responsible for running `grid_sample`**. CPU only implementation would be fine (although using Apple's Metal for GPU speedups would be great).

As I'm not into Swift, I've gathered a few resources which might help you:

- https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/custom-operators - starting point, Python only, quite easy, only registering layer for conversion
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlcustomlayer - API of the layer which one would have to code in Swift
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/creating_a_custom_layer - more about aforementioned (but not much)
- https://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/ - blog post with example and dispatching layer to devices (GPU, CPU). Needs Swift (CPU version), Metal (GPU implementation). Eventual Metal implementation might be based off PyTorch's CUDA impl, CPU and Swift might also be related.
  3 years old, so be aware of that, swish activation layer, seems to be a good starting point (and other posts from the same author cast some light on the CoreML itself).
- https://github.com/hollance/CoreML-Custom-Layers - repo for the above

**Pros:**

- Possibility to use loops and finer control over the algorithm
- Might be easier as we're not limited to operations which CoreML can currently read

**Cons:**

- Two languages
- Sparse documentation

Comment: Hello, have you any progress with `grid_sample` convertion?

Comment: Try use: 
model = ct.convert(source_model, convert_to="mlprogram")
It's support grid_sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently some good soul saw our struggles and provided custom op using MIL (intermediate representation language of CoreML).

#### [Blog post](https://medium.com/mwm-io/bring-machine-learning-into-your-ios-apps-part-1-f34628c96a7a) where I found the solution and [gist with grid sample](https://gist.github.com/virgileboulanger/afd99e95150362261a178e164375be24)

I am not sure why OP did not post it here, but please do respond with a comment if you want to take some SO points for your solution!

Full operation conversion code below:

```
from coremltools.converters.mil import register_torch_op, register_op
from coremltools.converters.mil.mil.ops.defs._op_reqs import *

# Custom operator for `torch.nn.functional.grid_sample`
@register_op(doc_str="Custom Grid Sampler", is_custom_op=True)
class custom_grid_sample(Operation):
    input_spec = InputSpec(
        x = TensorInputType(),
        grid = TensorInputType(),
        mode = StringInputType(const=True, optional=True),
        padding_mode = StringInputType(const=True, optional=True),
        align_corners = BoolInputType(const=True, optional=True)
    )

    bindings = {
        "class_name": "CustomGridSampler",
        "input_order": ["x", "grid"],
        "parameters": ["mode", "padding_mode", "align_corners"],
        "description": "Custom Grid Sampler"
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(custom_grid_sample, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def type_inference(self):
        x_type = self.x.dtype
        x_shape = self.x.shape

        grid_type = self.grid.dtype
        grid_shape = self.grid.shape

        assert len(x_shape) == len(grid_shape) == 4
        assert grid_shape[-1] == 2

        shape = list(x_shape)
        shape[-2] = grid_shape[1]
        shape[-1] = grid_shape[2]
        return types.tensor(x_type, tuple(shape))


@register_torch_op
def grid_sampler(context, node):
    inputs = _get_inputs(context, node)
    x = inputs[0]
    grid = inputs[1]
    mode = node.attr.get("mode", "bilinear")
    padding_mode = node.attr.get("padding_mode", "zeros")
    align_corners = node.attr.get("align_corners", False)
    x = mb.custom_grid_sample(
        x=x,
        grid=grid,
        mode=mode,
        padding_mode=padding_mode,
        align_corners=align_corners,
        name=node.name
    )
    context.add(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not exact answer, rather some research. `grid_sample` by it's nature is sparse matrix operation, the idea is to try make it dense. The code below is demonstrates how it could be done. It may be slow, and requires `grid` to be static to eliminate `grid_sample` from model to be converted, but kinda works.

The goal is to get our transformation in linear form. Here, to get the dense matrix, we feed unit diagonal to 'grid_sample', and the result is matrix holding transform we are looking for. To do named transform, multiply flattened image to this matrix.
As you can see batch=1 here, the conversion must be done for each `grid` independently.

Your code:

```
in_sz  = 2;    out_sz = 4;    batch  = 1;    ch     = 3

class GridSample(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, inputs, grid):
        # Rest could be the default behaviour, e.g. bilinear
        return torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(inputs, grid, align_corners=True)

image = torch.randn( batch, ch, in_sz, in_sz)  # (batch, in_channels, width, height)
grid = torch.randint(low=-1, high=2, size=( batch, out_sz, out_sz, 2)).float()

layer = GridSample()
scripted = torch.jit.trace(layer, (image, grid))
print(scripted(image, grid))
```

out:

```
tensor([[[[-0.8226, -0.4457, -0.3382, -0.0795],
          [-0.4457, -0.0052, -0.8226, -0.6341],
          [-0.4457, -0.8226, -0.4457, -0.6341],
          [-0.4510, -0.3382, -0.4457, -0.0424]],

         [[-1.0090, -1.6029, -1.3813, -0.1212],
          [-1.6029, -2.7920, -1.0090, -1.3060],
          [-1.6029, -1.0090, -1.6029, -1.3060],
          [-0.5651, -1.3813, -1.6029, -1.4566]],

         [[ 0.1482,  0.7313,  0.8916,  1.8723],
          [ 0.7313,  0.8144,  0.1482,  0.4398],
          [ 0.7313,  0.1482,  0.7313,  0.4398],
          [ 1.0103,  0.8916,  0.7313,  1.3434]]]])
```

Conversion:

```
oness  = torch.ones( in_sz*in_sz )
diagg  = torch.diag( oness ).reshape( 1, in_sz*in_sz, in_sz, in_sz )
denser = torch.nn.functional.grid_sample( diagg, grid, align_corners=True).reshape( in_sz*in_sz, out_sz*out_sz ).transpose(0,1)
print (denser.shape)
print (image.shape)
image_flat = image.reshape( batch, ch, in_sz*in_sz )
print (image_flat.shape)
print( torch.nn.functional.linear( image_flat, denser ).reshape( batch, ch, out_sz, out_sz ) )
```

Out:

```
torch.Size([16, 4])
torch.Size([1, 3, 2, 2])
torch.Size([1, 3, 4])
tensor([[[[-0.8226, -0.4457, -0.3382, -0.0795],
          [-0.4457, -0.0052, -0.8226, -0.6341],
          [-0.4457, -0.8226, -0.4457, -0.6341],
          [-0.4510, -0.3382, -0.4457, -0.0424]],

         [[-1.0090, -1.6029, -1.3813, -0.1212],
          [-1.6029, -2.7920, -1.0090, -1.3060],
          [-1.6029, -1.0090, -1.6029, -1.3060],
          [-0.5651, -1.3813, -1.6029, -1.4566]],

         [[ 0.1482,  0.7313,  0.8916,  1.8723],
          [ 0.7313,  0.8144,  0.1482,  0.4398],
          [ 0.7313,  0.1482,  0.7313,  0.4398],
          [ 1.0103,  0.8916,  0.7313,  1.3434]]]])
```

Well, may be not very effective, I hope this amuses at least.